# NSPredicate that is the equivalent of SQL's LIKE

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data, nspredicate

I'm looking for a way to use `NSPredicate` to set a `LIKE` condition to fetch objects. In addition to that, an `OR` would be useful as well. I'm trying to do something where if a user searches "James" I can write an `NSPredicate` that will do the equivalent of:

```
select * from users where firstname LIKE '%James%' OR lastname LIKE '%James%';
```

Answer (score 129, accepted):

```
NSString *_mySearchKey = @"James";
NSPredicate *_myPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(firstname CONTAINS[cd] %@) OR (lastname CONTAINS[cd] %@)", _mySearchKey, _mySearchKey];
```

Comment: Found ! It means Case & Diacritic insensitive

Comment: @AlexReynolds why don't you use LIKE ?

Comment: A better question is: Why should I use LIKE, instead?

Comment: this is not working with empty string @"".  Any suggestions? [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@", strFilter] not working when strFilter is @""

Comment: Check if the string is empty before running your predicate test, and handle that case separately. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899209/how-do-i-test-if-a-string-is-empty-in-objective-c

Comment: This answer will not give results as LIKE does for eg: S% give results starting with S, whereas contains will give results not starting with `S` will result listing containing S, which is not a correct result, whats the solution for that?

Answer (score 38):

The `CONTAINS` operator will certainly work just fine.  If you're looking for a more direct correlation, then you can also use the LIKE operator (`*` = 0 or more characters, `?` = 1 character):

```
NSString *_mySearchKey = @"James";
NSPredicate *_myPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstname LIKE '*%1$@*' OR lastname LIKE '*%1$@*'", _mySearchKey];
```

For reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215868

Comment: I know that's a long time ago, but this doesn't work, since NSPredicate doesn't substitute quoted content '%@' will stay '%@'...

Comment: beginswith[c] does it for me but still, has anyone managed to generate a dynamic LIKE query such as '%@*'

Comment: The trick to using like is to include the * marks in the argument. ie: `NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K LIKE[cd] %@", kMDItemDisplayName, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"*%@*", appname]];`

Comment: What does the 1$@ do?

Comment: @shim identifies specifically the first argument. Contrast with if the author had just used `%@` twice; in that case he'd have needed to supply `_mySearchKey` twice. E.g. `NSLog(@"%1$@ %1$@", @"Hat");` will output "Hat Hat".

Answer (score 10):

Another possibility

```
@"firstname beginswith[c] James"
```

As a nice alternative to contains

Sometimes contains isn't always the right answer

Comment: Does not match "SuperJames" :) beginswith is not equal to sql's like '%foo%'