# NSPredicate, executeFetchRequest crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I'm doing a Core Data tutorial and I keep getting a crash. It's a objc_exception_throw.

I create a method called loadTableData and call it in viewDidLoad

```
-(void)loadTableData{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[self appDelegate]managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Label" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"label like %@", [context objectWithID: self.labelID]];

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];


    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSError *error = nil;
    self.artistArray = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

It gets stuck here

```
self.artistArray = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Commenting out the predicate alloc/init and setPredicate method call results in an app that doesn't crash, but doesn't do what I want.

See entities and relationships below.

[image: Core Data Entities]

In LabelViewController here is additional code to show how [context objectWithID: self.labelID] is set

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MLBLArtistViewController *artistViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ArtistViewController"];

    Label *label = [self.labelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    artistViewController.labelID = [label objectID];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:artistViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Is "label" a property of the "Label" entity? What type does it have? And what kind of object returns `[context objectWithID: self.labelID]` ?

Comment: @MartinR Please see edited question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it seems that you want to fetch "Artist" objects, not "Label" objects:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Artist" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

Next, `LIKE` or `CONTAINS` are for testings *strings*, you need a simple `==`:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"label == %@", [context objectWithID:self.labelID]];
```

*Remark:* It would be simpler to pass the `label` object itself to the pushed view controller,
instead of `[label objectID]`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a `CONTAINS` instead:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"label CONTAINS[cd] %@", [context objectWithID: self.labelID]];
```

You can use a LIKE but I like the simplicity of the CONTAINS, see this quesiton:
[NSPredicate that is the equivalent of SQL's LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740933/nspredicate-that-is-the-equivalent-of-sqls-like)

Comment: Cool tip, still crashes.

Comment: can you post the crash log?

Comment: Looks like you are passing in an object into your predicate rather than looking for a specific property? [context objectWithID: self.labelID]  Pretty sure that won't work.

Comment: 12/17/13 12:41:31.037 AM Xcode[551]: [MT] IDENavigableItemCoordinator: <DBGThreadNavigableItem 0x7fcf21733790: (supports Any DBGThread, represents: <DBGLLDBThread: 0x7fcf1f0d4740> - number:1 - name:Thread 1)> has 9 childItems but indexOfChildItemForIdentifier: '6574070280564460612' returned index of 9

Comment: See Martin R's comment above, important questions to answer