# Get the length of a String

Tags: swift, string

How do you get the length of a `String`? For example, I have a variable defined like:

```
var test1: String = "Scott"
```

However, I can't seem to find a length method on the string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [String length in Swift 1.2 and Swift 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29575140/string-length-in-swift-1-2-and-swift-2-0)

Comment: I had to migrate a lot of code manually because of Swift 3. So I decided to create extensions.
So now, if have to upgrade to a new major release, I need to migrate only the extension.
Here you can find some Swift 3 extensions I've created. https://github.com/tukur187/Swift3

Comment: Whatever solution you go for, you can [cross check the results](https://magic-tools-531.web.app/#!/tools/character-count) with an online tool

Answer (score 1368, accepted):

**As of Swift 4+**

It's just:

```
test1.count
```

for reasons.

(Thanks to Martin R)

**As of Swift 2:**

With Swift 2, Apple has changed global functions to protocol extensions, extensions that match any type conforming to a protocol. Thus the new syntax is:

```
test1.characters.count
```

(Thanks to JohnDifool for the heads up)

**As of Swift 1**

Use the count characters method:

```
let unusualMenagerie = "Koala &#128040;, Snail &#128012;, Penguin &#128039;, Dromedary &#128042;"
println("unusualMenagerie has \(count(unusualMenagerie)) characters")
// prints "unusualMenagerie has 40 characters"
```

right from the Apple Swift Guide

(note, for versions of Swift earlier than 1.2, this would be `countElements(unusualMenagerie)` instead)

for your variable, it would be

```
length = count(test1) // was countElements in earlier versions of Swift
```

Or you can use test1.utf16count

Comment: Interesting that countElements is a global function.  Is there a list of global functions?

Comment: @ScottWalter: cmd-click on a Swift symbol (ex: String) and you'll get to them. Near the top of the resulting file.

Comment: It was just too hard to add a str.length method. (raises his fist in anger)

Comment: @botbot: You can easily add one by extending the class. :)

Comment: The weird part is that Apple's document does have a length property in Swift:The number of Unicode characters in the receiver. (read-only)

Declaration
SWIFT
var length: Int { get }

Comment: @ScottWalter Dash.app, a document browser app, maintains a current list of global functions for the swift documentation set. Knowing which of those to use or what to look for isn't always obvious though.

Comment: countElements has been replaced by count in swift 1.2 (beta 1) There‘s no longer a separate countElements call for counting the size of collections vs count for ranges – it’s now just count for both.

Comment: `countElements` has been renamed to just `count` in Swift 1.2.

Comment: It's ridiculous that a "length" method wasn't added. This language is barely beta-quality, let alone release-quality.

Comment: With Swift 2, I can only get this to work: let len = test1.characters.count

Comment: Yes Apple has changed global functions to protocol extensions

Comment: @milesper Note that this is an O(n) operation and *not* the same as (str as NSString).length, which is equivalent to str.utf16.count and is O(1)

Comment: So Apple has changed this simple function three times in one year?! Am I the only feeling shaky ground under my feet?

Comment: Note that  with Swift 4, it will be `string.count`.

Comment: a language being made up on the fly - add some comment about swifts flying

Comment: It's a trap! They want you to focus on constantly changing your code for new language constructs instead of focusing on productivity. And then they deprecate older constructs so that you constantly need to keep on dancing. :/

Comment: test.text.count for swift 4

Answer (score 346):

## TLDR:

For **Swift 2.0 and 3.0,** use `test1.characters.count`. But, there are a few things you should know. So, read on.

## Counting characters in Swift

Before Swift 2.0, `count` was a global function. As of Swift 2.0, it can be called as a member function.

```
test1.characters.count
```

It will return the actual number of Unicode characters in a `String`, so it's the most correct alternative in the sense that, if you'd print the string and count characters by hand, you'd get the same result.

However, because of the way `Strings` are implemented in Swift, characters don't always take up the same amount of memory, so be aware that this behaves quite differently than the usual character count methods in other languages.

For example, you can also use `test1.utf16.count`

But, as noted below, the returned value is not guaranteed to be the same as that of calling `count` on `characters`.

From the language reference:

> Extended grapheme clusters can be composed of one or more Unicode
>   scalars. This means that different characters—and different
>   representations of the same character—can require different amounts of
>   memory to store. Because of this, characters in Swift do not each take
>   up the same amount of memory within a string’s representation. As a
>   result, the number of characters in a string cannot be calculated
>   without iterating through the string to determine its extended
>   grapheme cluster boundaries. If you are working with particularly long
>   string values, be aware that the characters property must iterate over
>   the Unicode scalars in the entire string in order to determine the
>   characters for that string.
>
> The count of the characters returned by the characters property is not
>   always the same as the length property of an NSString that contains
>   the same characters. The length of an NSString is based on the number
>   of 16-bit code units within the string’s UTF-16 representation and not
>   the number of Unicode extended grapheme clusters within the string.

An example that perfectly illustrates the situation described above is that of checking the length of a string containing a single emoji character, as pointed out by [n00neimp0rtant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/397230/n00neimp0rtant) in the comments.

```
var emoji = ""
emoji.characters.count             //returns 1
emoji.utf16.count                  //returns 2
```

Comment: I appreciate your detailed and cautionary answer, but I have to admit it's left me uneasy. You gave me 3 ways to get the length of a string, all with the disclaimer that the answers they give might not be what you expect. Is there truly no reliable way built into Swift to get an accurate, reliable length value of a string?

Comment: @n00neimp0rtant. Sorry if I did not make it clear. The first solution (`countElements()`)gets the exact number of characters in the String. It might be different from what you'd get from calling `[str length]` in Objective-C, because the `length` method assumes all characters in the string are composed of 16-bit code units, while `countElements()` gets the actual number of Unicode characters. However, most of the time all of the above alternatives will return the same results, specially if you're are working with English language common characters.

Comment: @n00neimp0rtant I tweaked my answer a little bit to try and make it more clear.

Comment: I see what you mean now. I just tried getting the length of a string containing a single Emoji character; Objective-C gave me a value of 4, and Swift gave me a value of 1. So it actually seems more accurate (and therefore, ironically "not what I'd expect" =P). Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @n00neimp0rtant Exactly! That's a perfect example. I'll even add it to the answer

Comment: I guess in the special case in which you want to determine if the string is empty or not, it doesn't really matter which method you use (i.e., the empty string has length 0 in every representation).

Comment: ...forget about that; it turns out there is an `isEmpty` property! (just found out)

Comment: For Swift 2.0, the "length" of a String can be returned using test1.characters.count (not test1.count).

Comment: **'String' has no member 'bridgeToObjectiveC' ** (swift 2.2, Xcode 7.3.1) also utf16.count instead of utf16Count

Comment: Also I get 2 characters for this lady:  using `.characters.count`. Looping over the characters, I get these: and


Answer (score 97):

<strike>Swift 1.2 Update: There's no longer a countElements for counting the size of collections. Just use the count function as a replacement: count("Swift")</strike>

<strike>Swift 2.0, 3.0 and 3.1:</strike>

> let strLength = string.characters.count

Swift 4.2 (4.0 onwards): [[Apple Documentation - Strings]](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID297)

> let strLength = string.count

Answer (score 65):

**Swift 1.1**

```
extension String {
    var length: Int { return countElements(self) }  // 
}
```

---

**Swift 1.2**

```
extension String {
    var length: Int { return count(self)         }  // 
}
```

---

**Swift 2.0**

```
extension String {
    var length: Int { return characters.count    }  // 
}
```

---

**Swift 4.2**

```
extension String {
    var length: Int { return self.count }           
}
```

---

```
let str = "Hello"
let count = str.length    // returns 5 (Int)
```

Comment: Yes, we need an abstraction layer for Swift's syntax which is changing on a monthly basis!

Comment: @Lee This doesn't work in swift 4. as characters is deprecated. The whac-a-mole run around continues. sigh

Answer (score 52):

**Swift 4**

`"string".count`

;)

**Swift 3**

```
extension String {
    var length: Int {
        return self.characters.count
    }
}
```

usage

`"string".length`

Comment: It returns String.CharacterView.IndexDistance. What about Int?

Comment: @GitSync where? I don't understand you

Comment: @Vyacheslav in swift 4 "string".count returns String.CharacterView.IndexDistance See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47203597/5389500 to get int in swift 3 and 4

Comment: I've tested this is the playground:

Comment: `//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

var str = "Hello, playground"

print(type(of: str.characters.count))
print(type(of: str.count))`

Comment: it yields `Int, Int`

Comment: `/// A type that represents the number of steps between a pair of
    /// indices.
    public typealias IndexDistance = Int`

Answer (score 26):

If you are just trying to see if a string is empty or not (checking for length of 0), Swift offers a simple boolean test method on `String`

```
myString.isEmpty
```

The other side of this coin was people asking in ObjectiveC how to ask if a string was empty where the answer was to check for a length of 0:

[NSString is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436173/nsstring-is-empty)

Answer (score 23):

### Swift 5.1, 5

```
let flag = ""

print(flag.count)
// Prints "1" --  Counts the characters and emoji as length 1

print(flag.unicodeScalars.count)
// Prints "2" --  Counts the unicode lenght ex. "A" is 65

print(flag.utf16.count)
// Prints "4"

print(flag.utf8.count)
// Prints "8"
```

Answer (score 20):

**tl;dr** If you want the length of a String type in terms of the number of human-readable characters, use **countElements()**. If you want to know the length in terms of the number of *extended grapheme clusters*, use **endIndex**. Read on for details.

The **String** type is implemented as an ordered collection (i.e., sequence) of Unicode characters, and it conforms to the **CollectionType** protocol, which conforms to the **_CollectionType** protocol, which is the input type expected by **countElements()**. Therefore, **countElements()** can be called, passing a **String** type, and it will return the count of characters.

However, in conforming to **CollectionType**, which in turn conforms to **_CollectionType**, **String** also implements the **startIndex** and **endIndex** computed properties, which actually represent the position of the index *before* the first character cluster, and position of the index *after* the last character cluster, respectively. So, in the string "ABC", the position of the index before A is 0 and after C is 3. Therefore, **endIndex** = 3, which is also the length of the string.

So, **endIndex** can be used to get the length of any String type, then, right?

Well, not always...Unicode characters are actually *extended grapheme clusters*, which are sequences of one *or more* Unicode scalars combined to create a single human-readable character.

```
let circledStar: Character = "\u{2606}\u{20DD}" // ☆⃝
```

**circledStar** is a single character made up of U+2606 (a white star), and U+20DD (a combining enclosing circle). Let's create a **String** from **circledStar** and compare the results of **countElements()** and **endIndex**.

```
let circledStarString = "\(circledStar)"
countElements(circledStarString) // 1
circledStarString.endIndex // 2
```

Answer (score 18):

In Swift 2.0 `count` doesn't work anymore. You can use this instead:

```
var testString = "Scott"
var length = testString.characters.count
```

Answer (score 16):

Here's something shorter, and more natural than using a global function:

```
aString.utf16count
```

I don't know if it's available in beta 1, though. But it's definitely there in beta 2.

Comment: See Cezar’s answer. This will not necessarily give you the number of “characters” in the string, for most people’s definition of “character”. Then again, neither did Objective-C — it’s up to you to decide whether you care or not.

Answer (score 13):

Updated for Xcode 6 beta 4, change method utf16count --> utf16Count

```
 var test1: String = "Scott"
 var length =  test1.utf16Count
```

Or

```
 var test1: String = "Scott"
 var length = test1.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF16StringEncoding)
```

Comment: When you’re using complex strings with emoji, the answer with `utf16count` will be wrong

Answer (score 12):

As of Swift 1.2 `utf16Count` has been removed. You should now use the global `count()` function and pass the UTF16 view of the string. Example below...

```
let string = "Some string"
count(string.utf16)
```

Comment: Is it slower than .utf16count?

Comment: It seems the same speed as .utf16count, much faster than count(string)

Answer (score 11):

For Xcode 7.3 and Swift 2.2.

```
let str = ""
```

1. If you want the number of visual characters:

   ```
   str.characters.count
   ```
2. If you want the "16-bit code units within the string’s UTF-16 representation":

   ```
   str.utf16.count
   ```

---

Most of the time, **1** is what you need.

When would you need **2**? I've found a use case for **2**:

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern:"", 
    options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.UseUnixLineSeparators)
let str = ""
let result = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(str, 
    options: NSMatchingOptions.WithTransparentBounds, 
    range: NSMakeRange(0, str.utf16.count), withTemplate: "dog")
print(result) // dogdogdogdogdogdog
```

If you use **1**, the result is incorrect:

```
let result = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(str, 
    options: NSMatchingOptions.WithTransparentBounds, 
    range: NSMakeRange(0, str.characters.count), withTemplate: "dog")
print(result) // dogdogdog
```

Answer (score 9):

You could try like this

```
var test1: String = "Scott"
var length =  test1.bridgeToObjectiveC().length
```

Comment: That's the same as `test1.utf16count`

Comment: @vladof well, it “kind of” works. See Cezar’s answer.

Answer (score 8):

in Swift 2.x the following is how to find the length of a string

```
let findLength = "This is a string of text"
findLength.characters.count
```

returns 24

Answer (score 7):

Swift 2.0:
Get a count: `yourString.text.characters.count`

Fun example of how this is useful would be to show a character countdown from some number (150 for example) in a UITextView:

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
    yourStringLabel.text = String(150 - yourStringTextView.text.characters.count)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In swift4 I have always used `string.count` till today I have found that

```
string.endIndex.encodedOffset
```

is the better substitution because it is faster - for 50 000 characters string is about 6 time faster than `.count`. The `.count` depends on the string length but `.endIndex.encodedOffset` doesn't.

But there is one NO. It is not good for strings with emojis, it will give wrong result, so only `.count` is correct.

Answer (score 5):

In **Swift 4** : 
If the string does not contain unicode characters then use the following

```
let str : String = "abcd"
let count = str.count // output 4
```

If the string contains unicode chars then use the following :

```
let spain = "España"
let count1 = spain.count // output 6
let count2 = spain.utf8.count // output 7
```

Comment: Why would you want to use `utf8.count`? That doesn't give the count of characters. It gives the number of bytes needed for the UTF-8 encoding of the string.

Answer (score 4):

In Xcode 6.1.1

```
extension String {    
    var length : Int { return self.utf16Count  }
}
```

I think that brainiacs will change this on every minor version.

Answer (score 4):

Get string value from your textview or textfield:

```
let textlengthstring = (yourtextview?.text)! as String
```

Find the count of the characters in the string:

```
let numberOfChars = textlength.characters.count
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I ended up doing

```
let replacementTextAsDecimal = Double(string)

if string.characters.count > 0 &&
    replacementTextAsDecimal == nil &&
    replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator == nil {
        return false
}
```

Comment: I think you are trying to do more than just getting the length of the string, and in any case this looks incomplete (shouldn't there also be a `return true` case?). Can you please double check and, in case, [edit] your answer? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4 update comparing with swift 3**

Swift 4 removes the need for a characters array on String. This means that you can directly call `count` on a string without getting characters array first.

```
"hello".count                  // 5
```

Whereas in swift 3, you will have to get characters array and then count element in that array. Note that this following method is still available in swift 4.0 as you can still call `characters` to access characters array of the given string

```
"hello".characters.count       // 5
```

Swift 4.0 also adopts Unicode 9 and it can now interprets grapheme clusters. For example, counting on an emoji will give you 1 while in swift 3.0, you may get counts greater than 1.

```
"".count // Swift 4.0 prints 1, Swift 3.0 prints 2
"‍❤️‍‍".count // Swift 4.0 prints 1, Swift 3.0 prints 4
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4

```
let str =  "Your name"

str.count
```

Remember: Space is also counted in the number

Answer (score 4):

You can get the length simply by writing an extension:

```
extension String {
    // MARK: Use if it's Swift 2
    func stringLength(str: String) -> Int {
        return str.characters.count
    }

    // MARK: Use if it's Swift 3
    func stringLength(_ str: String) -> Int {
        return str.characters.count
    }

    // MARK: Use if it's Swift 4
    func stringLength(_ str: String) -> Int {
        return str.count
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Best way to count String in Swift is this:

```
var str = "Hello World"
var length = count(str.utf16)
```

Comment: You should use just count(str). Try tu use count(str.utf16) with sub string advance()

Answer (score 2):

String and NSString are toll free bridge so you can use all methods available to NSString with swift String

```
let x = "test" as NSString
let y : NSString = "string 2"
let lenx = x.count
let leny = y.count
```

Answer (score 2):

```
test1.characters.count
```

will get you the number of letters/numbers etc in your string.

ex:

```
test1 = "StackOverflow"

print(test1.characters.count)
```

(**prints** "***13***")

Answer (score 2):

Apple made it different from other major language. The current way is to call:

test1.characters.count

However, to be careful, when you say length you mean the count of characters not the count of bytes, because those two can be different when you use non-ascii characters.

For example;
      `"你好啊hi".characters.count` will give you 5 but this is not the count of the bytes.
      To get the real count of bytes, you need to do `"你好啊hi".lengthOfBytes(using: String.Encoding.utf8)`. This will give you 11.

Answer (score 2):

Right now (in Swift 2.3) if you use:

```
myString.characters.count
```

the method will return a "Distance" type, if you need the method to return an Integer you should type cast like so:

```
var count = myString.characters.count as Int
```

Comment: The  `Distance` of `String.CharacterView` *is* `Int`, there should be no need for this cast.

Answer (score 2):

my two cents for swift 3/4

If You need to conditionally compile

```
    #if swift(>=4.0)
            let len = text.count
        #else
            let len = text.characters.count
        #endif
```

Comment: Good point. I rather upgrade to swift 4 across the board tho.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "Hello, playground"
var newString = str as NSString    

countElements(str)
```

This counts the characters in Regular Swift String

```
countElements((newString as String))
```

This counts the characters in a NSString

Answer (score 0):

Using **Xcode 6.4**, **Swift 1.2** and **iOS 8.4**:

```
    //: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

    import UIKit

    var str = "  He\u{2606}  "
    count(str) // 7

    let length = count(str.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())) as Int // 3
    println(length == 3) // true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this function to your extention

```
extension NSString { 
    func charLength() -> Int {
        return count(self as String)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.utf8.count` and `str.utf16.count` which, I think, are the best solution

Answer (score 0):

`test1.endIndex` gives the same result as `test1.characters.count` on Swift 3

Answer (score 0):

#### Universal Swift 4 and 3 solution

```
/**
 * Since swift 4 There is also native count, But it doesn't return Int
 * NOTE: was: var count:Int { return self.characters.count }
 * EXAMPLE: "abc".count//Output: 4
 */
extension String{
    var count:Int {
        return self.distance(from: self.startIndex, to: self.endIndex)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4.1 and Xcode 9.4.1

To get length in Objective c and Swift is different. In Obj-c we use **length** property, but in Swift we use **count** property

Example :

```
//In Swift
let stringLenght = "This is my String"
print(stringLenght.count)

//In Objective c
NSString * stringLenght = @"This is my String";
NSLog(@"%lu", stringLenght.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10.1

In Swift strings can be treated like an array of individual characters. So each character in string is like an element in array. To get the length of a string use **yourStringName.count** property.

In **Swift**

`yourStringName.characters.count` property in deprecated. So directly use `strLength.count` property.

```
let strLength = "This is my string"
print(strLength.count)
//print(strLength.characters.count) //Error: 'characters' is deprecated: Please use String or Substring directly
```

If **Objective C**

```
NSString *myString = @"Hello World";
NSLog(@"%lu", [myString length]); // 11
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5.0 strings can be treated as an array of individual characters. So, to return the length of a string you can use **yourString.count** to count the number of items in the characters array.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for a cleaner way to get length of a string checkout this library which has bunch of extensions to the Swift built in classes http://www.dollarswift.org/#length

Using this library you can just do `"Some Str".length`

Answer (score -1):

You could use SwiftString (https://github.com/amayne/SwiftString) to do this.

`"string".length // 6`

DISCLAIMER: I wrote this extension