# How to you set the maximum number of characters that can be entered into a UITextField using swift?

Tags: uitextfield, swift

How do you limit the number of characters in a `UITextField` to `10`, and if the user enters more than `10`, only record the first 10 characters?

Answer (score 5):

This solution deals with a user pasting text or tapping delete key too.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let length = count(textField.text.utf16) + count(string.utf16) - range.length

    return length <= 10 

}
```

Comment: what is the ```count``` method? Currently using Swift 3.

Comment: @Ivan I switched to React Native but this is probably what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24037756/4953199

Answer (score 2):

You can check the text before it gets displayed by implementing the `UITextFieldDelegate`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    textField(textField: UITextField!,
    shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,
                replacementString string: String!) -> Bool {

        var shouldChange = false

        if countElements(textField.text) < 10 { 
            shouldChange = true
        }

        return shouldChange
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I implement this function so my 'UITextField' only will take 10 chars?

Comment: This answer is incorrect. It makes no attempt to deal with a user pasting text or tapping the delete key.

Answer (score 0):

Slight modification to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30577739/10752877) from [@tugce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4953199/tugce):

```swift
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    // You can check for other things besides length here as well.
    return isValidLength(textField: textField, range: range, string: string)
}

private func isValidLength(textField: UITextField, range: NSRange, string: String) -> Bool {
    let length = ((textField.text ?? "").utf16).count + (string.utf16).count - range.length     
    return length <= 10
}
```

This addresses the question [@Ivan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4826571/ivan) asked:

> what is the count method? Currently using Swift 3.

It also helps check for other conditions without crowding one method too much. For example, could do something like this to check several conditions while keeping functions a little smaller:

```swift
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        
    return isValidKey(string: string) && isValidLength(textField: textField, range: range, string: string)
}
    
private func isDeleteKey(string: String) -> Bool {
    if let character = string.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        let isBackSpace = strcmp(character, "\\b")
        if (isBackSpace == -92) {
            return true
        }
    }
        
    return false
}
    
private func isNumericKey(string: String) -> Bool {
    return string.rangeOfCharacter(from: NSCharacterSet.decimalDigits) != nil
}
    
private func isValidLength(textField: UITextField, range: NSRange, string: String) -> Bool {
    let length = ((textField.text ?? "").utf16).count + (string.utf16).count - range.length
    return length <= 10
}
    
private func isValidKey(string: String) -> Bool {
    return isDeleteKey(string: string) || isNumericKey(string: string)
}
```

I'll also mention that to utilize `textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool` you'll need to conform to the `UITextFieldDelegate` and [set the delegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate) of the text field. e.g.:

```swift
class MyClass: UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

   init() {
      textField.delegate = self
   }
}
```