# max lengh for textfield while typing in swift

Tags: swift

How can I control the max length of each textfield?
For example, I want set max len for txtname = 10. So while typing, if the count of characters is more than 10, it should stop typing.
I use the below code but it doesn't work:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    guard let text = textField.text else { return true }
    let newLength = text.characters.count + string.characters.count - range.length
    return newLength <= 10 // Bool
}
```

Comment: Did you set the delegate for `UITextField`?

Comment: http://www.globalnerdy.com/2015/04/27/how-to-program-an-ios-text-field-that-takes-only-numeric-input-or-specific-characters-with-a-maximum-length/

Comment: vini app : oh no. now i set delegate and work. thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46513151/2303865

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223407/max-length-uitextfield