# Swift textfield input remove dash from phone number

Tags: swift

My `UITextField` `.keyboardType` is `.phonePad`.
It takes my phone number like 000-1234-1234.
But my `UITextField`  is limited by string.count < 11.
So I want to remove dashes like 00012341234.
What should I do?

Supplement:
I can remove dashes after the input number.
But I want the input removed from the number.
When I tap suggest number `UITextField` be filled none dashes number.

Comment: `string.filter { "0"..."9" ~= $0 }`

Comment: @LeoDabus How can use for it when I click phone number?

Comment: Add a target for editing changed as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46513151/2303865) and filter the character digits `text = String(text!.filter { "0"..."9" ~= $0 })`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove the - symbol by using `replacingOccurrences`:

```
let phoneNumber = "000-1234-1234"
let removeDashLine = phoneNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")
print(phoneNumber)
```

result will be:

```
00012341234
```