# How to use BindableObjects (EnviromentObject)?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Im using the new SwiftUI. I have a `UserUpdate` class which is a `Bindable Object` and I want to modify these variables and automatically Update the UI.

I update these Values successfully but the views in my UI struct isn't updating when I change the variable in the `UserUpdate` class.

It **only** changes when I modify the `@EnviromentObject` variable in the UI struct itself.

That's my Bindable Object Class:

```
final class UserUpdate: BindableObject {
    let didChange = PassthroughSubject<Any, Never>()

    var allUsers: [User] = [] {
        didSet {
            print(allUsers)
            didChange.send(allUsers)
        }
    }

    var firstName: String = "" {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(firstName)
        }
    }

    var lastName: String = "" {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(lastName)
        }
    }
}
```

That's my User class:

```
struct User: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let firstName, lastName: String
}
```

Here's how I configure my UI:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @EnvironmentObject var bindableUser: UserUpdate

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("All Users:").bold().padding(.leading, 10)
                List {
                    ForEach(bindableUser.allUsers) { user in
                        Text("\(user.firstName) \(user.lastName)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Here I modify the variables in `UserUpdate`:**

```
class TestBind {
    static let instance = TestBind()

    let userUpdate = UserUpdate()

    func bind() {
        let user = User(id: userUpdate.allUsers.count, firstName: "Heyy", lastName: "worked")
        userUpdate.allUsers.append(user)
    }
}
```

Comment: That's because your view variable(bindableUser) is bound to EnvirnomentObject stream. The view wouldn't know if you update some other stream.

Comment: And how can I solve that? I don't see why Bindable Object if useful then.

Comment: Have you bound your environment to the view in your scene delegate? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56476007/swiftui-textfield-max-length/56477309?noredirect=1#comment99546841_56477309

Comment: @Paulw11 I've done that already

Comment: `BindableObject` protocol is now renamed to `ObservableObject`, `ObjectBinding` is now `ObservedObject` and `didChange` is now `objectWillChange`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that I had to call the method from my UI to get it working so its on the same stream.

For example by this:

```
struct ContentView : View {
@EnvironmentObject var networkManager: NetworkManager

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button(action: {
            self.networkManager.getAllCourses()
        }, label: {
            Text("Get All Courses")
        })

        List(networkManager.courses.identified(by: \.name)) {
            Text($0.name)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not wrong, you should inject the `UserUpdate` instance in your `ContentView`, probably in the `SceneDelegate`, using `ContentView().environmentObject(UserUpdate())`.

In that case, you have 2 different instance of the `UserUpdate` class, the first one created in the `SceneDelegate`, and the second created in the `TestBind` class.

The problem is that you have one instance that is bond to view (and will trigger view reload on update), and the one that you actually modify (in `TestBind` class) which is totally unrelated to the view.

You should find a way to use **the same instance** in the view and in the `TestBind` class (for example by using `ContentView().environmentObject(TestBind.instance.userUpdate)`