# SwiftUI validation and vetoing for user input

Tags: validation, swiftui, combine

I'm looking to implement a generic validation/vetoing loop in SwiftUI - the sort of thing that should be pretty straightforward to do with a "single source of truth" framework

In short I want to:

- Have a generic control (lets say for instance a `TextField`)
- Apply a validation/veto on the update of that control (for instance, a user types text)
- Propagate the intended change into a validator, updating a `Binding` source object somewhere (ideally, an `@State` member inside the `View`)
- Feeding that value back into the control for display

It seems that for all the "single source of truth" talk Apple is kind of lying - injecting a validation stage into this chain seems difficult, especially without breaking encapsulation of the view

Note that I don't really want to solve *this* problem in particular - I'm looking for a pattern to implement (ie: replace the `String` and `TextField` with `Bool` and `Toggle` for example)

The following code shows my best attempt at doing the above loop

```
class ValidatedValue<T>: ObservableObject {

    let objectWillChange = ObservableObjectPublisher()

    var validator: (T, T)->T

    var value: T {
        get {
            _value
        }
        set {
            _value = validator(_value, newValue)
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }

    /// Backing value for the observable
    var _value: T

    init(_ value: T, validator: @escaping (T, T)->T) {
        self._value = value
        self.validator = validator
    }
}

struct MustHaveDTextField: View {

    @ObservedObject var editingValue: ValidatedValue<String>

    public var body: some View {
        return TextField(
            "Must have a d",
            text: $editingValue.value
    }
}
```

With the validated value defined well outside the scope of the `View`

```
ValidatedValue(
    "oddity has a d",
    validator: { current, new in
        if new.contains("d") {
            return new
        }
        else {
            return current
        }
    }
)
```

This *kind of* works as it will prevent you from modifying the string input if it contains no "d"s. However;

- The cursor state still moves on the text control past the point of validation
- It exposes what should be entirely internal state and requires passing that down from parents or via the `EnvironmentObject` (if you are doing this with `List`s of things...ow)

Either I'm missing something key, or I'm taking the wrong approach, or what Apple says is not what Apple does.

Modifying internal state during the loop like what is done [here](https://gist.github.com/darrarski/065520cc7095a7e0e33e72373feab3ac) or [here](https://gist.github.com/darrarski/b500960c857b403bfff25228b12aadef) is not good - they modify state inside the view loop which XCode flags as `undefined behaviour`. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56477309/3886090) also has a similar solution but again suffers from needing to put the validation logic *outside* the view - IMHO it should be self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

I won't claim it's the one-correct-way, but a way I've handled this is by expressing result of processed validation rules (in my case encoded within a combine pipeline) as result properties:

- `validationMessages: String[]`
- `isEverythingOK: Boolean`

I hooked up the validation by exposing `@Published` properties for the field inputs available to the user, and on the model I paired each with a combine Subject, sending updates using the `didSet{}` closure on the property. The rules for the validatation are all then included within the a Combine pipline on the model, and only the results are exposed.

There's a bit of sample code for how I handled it within [Using Combine](https://gum.co/usingcombine), and available on Github at [ReactiveForm.swift](https://github.com/heckj/swiftui-notes/blob/master/SwiftUI-Notes/ReactiveForm.swift) and [ReactiveFormModel.swift](https://github.com/heckj/swiftui-notes/blob/master/SwiftUI-Notes/ReactiveFormModel.swift)

I'll try to include the relevant bits here for example. Note that in the example, I'm intentionally exposing a publisher for the SwiftUI view, but really only to show that it's possible - not that it's a way to solve this particular solution.

In practice, I found formalizing or knowing exactly what you want displayed when the form *isn't* validated made a huge impact on how I developed the solution to it.

```swift
import Foundation
import Combine

class ReactiveFormModel : ObservableObject {

    @Published var firstEntry: String = "" {
        didSet {
            firstEntryPublisher.send(self.firstEntry)
        }
    }
    private let firstEntryPublisher = CurrentValueSubject<String, Never>("")

    @Published var secondEntry: String = "" {
        didSet {
            secondEntryPublisher.send(self.secondEntry)
        }
    }
    private let secondEntryPublisher = CurrentValueSubject<String, Never>("")

    @Published var validationMessages = [String]()
    private var cancellableSet: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

    var submitAllowed: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never>

    init() {

        let validationPipeline = Publishers.CombineLatest(firstEntryPublisher, secondEntryPublisher)
            .map { (arg) -> [String] in
                var diagMsgs = [String]()
                let (value, value_repeat) = arg
                if !(value_repeat == value) {
                    diagMsgs.append("Values for fields must match.")
                }
                if (value.count < 5 || value_repeat.count < 5) {
                    diagMsgs.append("Please enter values of at least 5 characters.")
                }
                return diagMsgs
            }

        submitAllowed = validationPipeline
            .map { stringArray in
                return stringArray.count < 1
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()

        let _ = validationPipeline
            .assign(to: \.validationMessages, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellableSet)
    }
}
```