# SwiftUI validate input in textfields

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to validate user input in a TextField by removing certain characters using a regular expression. Unfortunately, I am running into problems with the didSet method of the `text` var calling itself recursively.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class TextValidator: ObservableObject {

    @Published var text = "" {
        didSet {
            print("didSet")
            text = text.replacingOccurrences(
                of: "\\W", with: "", options: .regularExpression
            ) // `\W` is an escape sequence that matches non-word characters.
        }
    }

}


struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var textValidator = TextValidator()

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Type Here", text: $textValidator.text)
            .padding(.horizontal, 20.0)
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())

    }
}
```

On the [swift docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID617) (see the AudioChannel struct), Apple provides an example in which a property is re-assigned within its own didSet method and explicitly notes that this does not cause the didSet method to be called again. I did some testing in a playground and confirmed this behavior. However, things seem to work differently when I use an `ObservableObject` and a `Published` variable.

**How do I prevent the didSet method from calling itself recursively?**

I tried the examples in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56476007/swiftui-textfield-max-length), but none of them worked. Apple may have changed things since then, so this post is NOT a duplicate of that one.

Also, setting the text back to `oldValue` within the `didSet` method upon encountering invalid characters would mean that if a user pastes text, then the entire text would be removed, as opposed to only the invalid characters being removed. So that option won't work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try to validate what you want in the `TextField` `onRecive` method like this:

```swift
class TextValidator: ObservableObject {

    @Published var text = ""

}
```

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var textValidator = TextValidator()
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Type Here", text: $textValidator.text)
            .padding(.horizontal, 20.0)
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            .onReceive(Just(textValidator.text)) { newValue in
                let value = newValue.replacingOccurrences(
                    of: "\\W", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
                if value != newValue {
                    self.textValidator.text = value
                }
                print(newValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! I never knew that modifier existed!

Comment: Wow! This is solution I was looking for.  Need to look at combine now as many gems could have been there waiting to be discovered ... Many thanks

Answer (score 23):

Since SwiftUI 2 you can check the input using the **onChange** method and do any validations or changes there:

```
TextField("", value: $text)
    .onChange(of: text) { [text] newValue in
         // do any validation or alteration here.
         // 'text' is the old value, 'newValue' is the new one.
    }
```

Comment: How access the $text from a viewModel?

Comment: For ViewModel, Check the answer provided by @Mac3n. TextValidator can be used as a ViewModel

Answer (score 6):

Here is possible approach using proxy binding, which still also allow separation of view & view model logic

```
class TextValidator: ObservableObject {

    @Published var text = ""

    func validate(_ value: String) -> String {
        value.replacingOccurrences(
                of: "\\W", with: "", options: .regularExpression
            )
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var textValidator = TextValidator()

    var body: some View {
        let validatingText = Binding<String>(
                get: { self.textValidator.text },
                set: { self.textValidator.text = self.textValidator.validate($0) }
                )
        return TextField("Type Here", text: validatingText)
            .padding(.horizontal, 20.0)
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Do you why it is that the didSet method in my version of the code was recursively called? Also, could you explain your code a little?

Answer (score 2):

**Here's what I came up with:**

```
struct ValidatableTextField: View {
    let placeholder: String
    @State private var text = ""
    var validation: (String) -> Bool
  
    @Binding private var sourceText: String
  
    init(_ placeholder: String, text: Binding<String>, validation: @escaping (String) -> Bool) {
        self.placeholder = placeholder
        self.validation = validation
        self._sourceText = text
    
        self.text = text.wrappedValue
    }
  
    var body: some View {
        TextField(placeholder, text: $text)
            .onChange(of: text) { newValue in
                if validation(newValue) {
                    self.sourceText = newValue
                } else {
                  self.text = sourceText
                }
            }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
ValidatableTextField("Placeholder", text: $text, validation: { !$0.contains("%") })
```

**Note:** this code doesn't solve specifically your problem but shows how to deal with validations in general.

Change body to this to solve your problem:

```
TextField(placeholder, text: $text)
    .onChange(of: text) { newValue in
        let value = newValue.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\W", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
        if value != newValue {
            self.sourceText = newValue
            self.text = sourceText
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is great. It works in iOS 17 too.

Answer (score 1):

**2021 | SwiftUI 2**

Custom extension usage:

```
TextField("New Branch name", text: $model.newNameUnified)
    .ignoreSymbols( symbols: [" ", "\n"], string: $model.newNameUnified )
```

Extension:

```
@available(OSX 11.0, *)
public extension TextField {
    func ignoreSymbols(symbols: [Character], string: Binding<String>) -> some View {
         self.modifier( IgnoreSymbols(symbols: symbols, string: string)  )
    }
}

@available(OSX 11.0, *)
public struct IgnoreSymbols: ViewModifier {
    var symbols: [Character]
    var string: Binding<String>
    
    public func body (content: Content) -> some View
    {
        content.onChange(of: string.wrappedValue) { value in
            var newValue = value
        
            for symbol in symbols {
                newValue = newValue.replacingOccurrences(of: "\(symbol)", with: "")
            }
        
            if value != newValue {
                string.wrappedValue = newValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `didSet` and `willSet` are always called when setting values, and `objectWillChange` triggers an update to the `TextField` (which triggers `didSet` again), a loop was created when the underlying value is updated unconditionally in `didSet`.

Updating the underlying value conditionally breaks the loop.
For example:

```swift
import Combine

class TextValidator: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text = "" {
        didSet {
            if oldValue == text || text == acceptableValue(oldValue)  {
                return
            }
            text = acceptableValue(text)
        }
    }
    
    var acceptableValue: (String) -> String = { $0 }
}
```

---

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct TestingValidation: View {
    @StateObject var textValidator: TextValidator = {
        let o = TextValidator()
        o.acceptableValue = { $0.replacingOccurrences(
            of: "\\W", with: "", options: .regularExpression) }
        return o
    }()
    
    @StateObject var textValidator2: TextValidator = {
        let o = TextValidator()
        o.acceptableValue = { $0.replacingOccurrences(
                of: "\\D", with: "", options: .regularExpression) }
        return o
    }()
    
   
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Text("Word characters only")
                TextField("Type here", text: $textValidator.text)
                
                Text("Digits only")
                TextField("Type here", text: $textValidator2.text)
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 20.0)
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            .disableAutocorrection(true)
            .autocapitalization(.none)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dodge the bullet by using `UIViewRepresentable`:

```swift
struct CurrencyTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = UITextField
    
    private let textField = UITextField()
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        // config the textField as you like it
        textField.delegate = Validator()
        return textField
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        
    }
}

class Validator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        // validation happens here
        return true
    }
}
```