# TextField accept limited characters SwiftUi

Tags: swift, uitextfield, swiftui, swiftui-environment, swiftui-form

I am having one textfield and I am using it to enter email and when a user clicks the send button, the email is deleted from the same textfield and its placeholder changes to enter pin. So when the user enters pin, I would like to make the text field to be limited up to 6 characters. Is this possible? If yes, please help me I am new to SwiftUI.

```
TextField(placeholder, text: $text)
```

The `$text` changes according to the states email or pin

Comment: maybe this will work for you -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/58364685/7512091

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using `Publisher` and `onReceive`.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text:String = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            TextField("Enter text", text: $text)
                .onReceive(text.publisher.last()) { (output) in
                    if self.text.count>6{ //set count as you want
                        self.text = String(self.text.dropLast())
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Im getting the problem of undeclared publisher

Comment: Dont you declare some kind of publisher?

Comment: I'm not declared any variable, whole code i paste in ans.

Comment: When the user enters more characters they are being displayed shortly and then deleted is there a way how this can be prevented?