# Create max character length in UITextField using IBInspectable

Tags: swift, uitextfield, maxlength, ibinspectable

I want to create a max length to my textfield with `IBInspectable`, I see a answer to this on a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43099816/6800631) but I'm getting an error saying `Expression type '()' is ambiguous without more context`,

My code was

```swift
import UIKit

private var __maxLengths = [UITextField: Int]()
extension UITextField {
    @IBInspectable var maxLength: Int {
        get {
            guard let l = __maxLengths[self] else {
               return 150 // (global default-limit. or just, Int.max)
            }
            return l
        }
        set {
            __maxLengths[self] = newValue
            addTarget(self, action: #selector(fix), for: .editingChanged)
        }
    }
    @objc func fix(textField: UITextField) {
        let t = textField.text
        textField.text = t?.prefix(maxLength)
    }
}
```

and I'm getting an error pointing at `textField.text = t?.prefix(maxLength)` with an error message saying `Expression type '()' is ambiguous without more context`,

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Can you remove `@objc` annotation in front of func fix? I think it causes this error.

Comment: @Sung-JongWillKim `@objc` is required

Comment: oh, selector is linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift 5, String's `prefix` method returns a value of type `String.SubSequence`

```
func prefix(_ maxLength: Int) -> Substring
```

You'll need to convert this to a `String` type.

One way to do this might be:

```
let s = textField.text!.prefix(maxLength) // though UITextField.text is defined as an optional String, can be safely force-unwrapped as the default value is an empty string even when set to nil
textField.text = String(s)
```

or if you prefer a single-line solution:

```
textField.text = String(textField.text!.prefix(maxLength))
```

Comment: UITextField `text` property default value is an empty string. Keeping `t` optional is pointless

Comment: UITextField.text is defined as an optional String. I was just keeping inline with OP's original code.

open var text: String? // default is nil

Comment: UITextField `text` property value will NEVER be nil

Comment: Thanks for keeping me honest. The "Jump to definition" action reveals what appears to be an outdated comment in the UITextField code. I'll edit the answer