# Swift: Limit Characters # in textField without disabling/interfering with other functions

Tags: swift, uitextfield, character, uitextfielddelegate

I want to limit the number of characters a user can use in a textField. I took a function from this link: [Max length UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223407/max-length-uitextfield-swift) (Imanou Petit)

However, in my viewDidLoad() I have several textFields that I'm already referencing the delegate because I want the keyboard to "Return" when the user presses the `Return` key on the keyboard. This I'm doing through the `textFieldShouldReturn` like this (I also have a touchesBegan method but I want the user to also have the option of the `Return` key):

```
 func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {


 self.stuffOneTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    self.linkTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    self.descriptionTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    self.ogTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    self.priceTextField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true

}
```

If I add in this function below to the viewDidLoad, then the 'Return' key on the keyboard doesn't work and it limits ALL of the textFields (I have 5).

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.stuffOneTextField.delegate = self
    self.linkTextField.delegate = self
    self.descriptionTextField.delegate = self
    self.ogTextField.delegate = self
    self.priceTextField.delegate = self
}

  func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    guard let text = textField.text else { return true }
    let newLength = text.characters.count + string.characters.count - range.length
        return newLength <= limitLength
   }
```

I only need to limit 2 textFields. I've tried just putting in the specific textField name instead of all the textFields as `textField`s and then it limits 1 textField and doesn't let me type in the others... Very strange...

How do I go around this?

Any help means a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're being given the `textField` that is changing characters in the delegate function.  Here, you can compare it to the specific fields that you want to limit:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    guard let text = textField.text else { return true }
    if !(textField == stuffOneTextField || textField == descriptionTextField) {
        return true
    }
    let newLength = text.characters.count + string.characters.count - range.length
    return newLength <= limitLength
}
```

Also, `func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool` is giving you a text field, and you can call `resignFirstResponder()` on that, if that is what you want to do there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where do I specify how long I want to limit the characters? Confused by the newLength constant and what's being returned... And where is this method being placed? Within another method? @Don

Comment: I've updated the answer to show that this would be in the body of the func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) function.  What's being returned is a boolean value indicating whether the typed string is under your size limit, limitLength.  As in the answer to the question you linked to above, `limitLength` is a constant defined in your class.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you so much.