# Method swizzled in objective-c is effective in everywhere

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category, method-swizzling

I create a category to method swizzled `UITextField`, it's name like `UITextField+MaxLength`, I implement the `+load` method to do swizzled, but I didn't import it in prefix header or other files, just import it in `SomeViewController`.

I think the swizzled should only work in `SomeViewController`, but why the swizzled method be invoke in every `UITextField` even a `UISearchBar`? and the `+load` method be invoke when I run the app?

## Edit

I think I need point out why I using swizzled, because of I want to using KVO to observe the text changed, so I swizzled the `setText` and associate a property `NSNumber` named `displayLength`, so, If I do not use KVO, I can remove the swizzled part of this category and I can do cut substring to specific max length.

Comment: That's just how swizzling works.  Use the textfield delegate methods if you want to limit the length for a specific field.

Comment: It is really hard to me to understand you. However, if you want to use KVO, just go ahead. You do not need to do method swizzling for it. KVO solves your problem and works on a per instance base. (This is, because it uses isa swizzling and overrides methods instead of swizzling a method.)

Answer (score 2):

Swizzling occurs at runtime; if you perform a swizzle, it genuinely changes the implementation of that class's method. It's just as if you altered the code to `UITextField`.

This is why method swizzling is such a rare and dangerous thing. If you just want to alter specific instances of `UITextField`, subclass (or, guessing your intentions from your category title, use a delegate).

Comment: Hum, I think my problem is why the load be invoke when I do nothing, but In my project, I use some 3rd party just like what I do, the load did't invoke until I use it, thanks for your suggest, but If I implement the delegate method in every where I use `UITextField`, I will getting lots of duplicate code, right?

Comment: No need to duplicate code--if all of your text fields behave the same way, you can give them all the same delegate.

Comment: Maybe I know what you mean, but if another developer need to implement same delegate method, I should make a subclass to the delegate?

Comment: This is sort of a different question now. Luckily, someone's already answered it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223407/max-length-uitextfield

Comment: I know I can do it with delegate method and I do this after I create this category, but I want to using category because of sometimes I need implement delegate method  `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` to do other things, do you know what I mean? If have another way to solve this problem, maybe I can use the other way to implement what I want.

Comment: I think I need point out why I using swizzled, because of I want to using KVO to observe the text changed, so I swizzled the `setText` and associate a property `NSNumber` named `displayLength`, so, If I do not use KVO, I can remove the swizzled part of this category and I can do cut substring to specific max length.