# How to allow CollectionViewCell textfield with all character in capital letter with character limit 1 in iOS Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to allow CollectionViewCell textfield with all character(only alphabates) in  uppercase with character limit 1 if user enter lowercase textfield convert it into uppercase in iOS Swift 3 ?

Answer (score 1):

**In Swift 3, 4:**

First add this line of code. It will Capitalized you keyboard.

```
yourTextField.autocapitalizationType = .allCharacters
```

Then set delegate to your desired textfield like that

```
yourTextField.delegate = self
```

Now implement this delegate method of textfield. This method listen your keypress.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    // check your char limit here & capitalized char based on your requirement.
    yourTextField.text = textField.text?.uppercased()
    return true
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
yourTextfield.autocapitalizationType = .allCharacters
```

for character limit you can refer this : [Max length UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223407/max-length-uitextfield)

Comment: yourTextfield.autocapitalizationType = .allCharacters. This is not working for all text in textfield.

Comment: try this  http://beyond925.blogspot.in/2015/09/ios-swift-force-all-characters-to-be.html