# How to get length of text enter in search bar?

Tags: swift, uisearchbar

I want to get the length of the text that is entered in a `UISearchBar`

I use the function that is called when the the searcbbar text starts editing.

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar!) {
    println("EDITING")
    //TODO: Get length of text entered in searchBar
}
```

This doesn't work:

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar!) {
    println("EDITING")
    //TODO: Get length of text entered in searchBar
    //Doesn't work. Error: String doesn't have a member named length
    searchBar.text.length
}
```

How can i retrieve the length of the entered text?

Ended up doing this:

```
searchBar.text.bridgeToObjectiveC().length
```

Comment: See there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037711/get-the-length-of-a-string

Comment: @Bas, as you found a solution you can post it as the answer and accept, so question will have a resolution. If somebody finds a better way, I am sure they will provide their variant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is simply that the `text` property, like most objects arriving from the Cocoa API, might be nil. You have to assure Swift that it is not. Like this:

```
let len = countElements(searchBar.text!)
```