# What's the most efficient way to determine if a Swift string is shorter than a certain length

Tags: swift

`s` is a native Swift string consisted of ASCII characters only. It could be arbitrary long. What's the most efficient way to figure out if `s` is short than a certain length (say, 100k)?

`if countElements(s) < 100_000` is not the most efficient, as `countElements` is O(n) complexity and `s` could have billions of characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're *sure* you don't need to worry about anything other than ASCII, you can use the `utf16Count` property (which is the `length` property of the bridged `NSString`):

```
let stringLength = superLongString.utf16Count
```

If you want to be able to handle Unicode you need to walk the string, you just don't want to walk the *whole* string. Here's a function to count just up to your limit:

```
func lengthLessThanMax(#string: String, maximum max: Int) -> Bool {
    var idx = string.startIndex
    var count = 0
    while idx < string.endIndex && count < max {
        ++count
        idx = idx.successor()
    }
    return count < max
}

lengthLessThanMax(string: "Hello!", maximum: 10)
// true
lengthLessThanMax(string: "Hello! Nice to meet you!", maximum: 10)
// false
```

Comment: Are you sure getting the `length` of an `NSString` backed by a Swift `String` is O(1) not O(n)? What about `-utf16Count` for a Swift string? How that bridging works under the hood?

Comment: Yes - the `length` property on `NSString` returns the number of Unicode characters, while in Swift, each element of a `String` can be made up of multiple Unicode characters. It's that second part that is hard and makes Swift strings not easily countable (i.e., you need to traverse the string to know how many characters it has). Ole Begemann has a [great post on Swift strings](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-strings/) that goes into the details more.

Comment: @Ethan Forgot about `.utf16Count` - that's actually added by Foundation; it's the same as using the length of the bridged NSString.

Answer (score -1):

just chose what your want:

```
var emoji = ""
countElements(emoji)              //returns 1
emoji.utf16Count                  //returns 2
emoji.bridgeToObjectiveC().length //returns 2
```

find from [Get the length of a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037711/get-the-length-of-a-string)