# String length in Swift 1.2 and Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, string

In the previous version of Swift, I had the following code.

```
func myfunc(mystr: String) {
    if mystr.utf16Count >= 3 {
```

With the latest release of Swift 1.2, I now get the following error.

```
'utf16Count' is unavailable: Take the count of a UTF-16 view instead, i.e. count(str.utf16)
```

So I change my code as follows:

```
func myfunc(mystr: String) {
    if count(mystr.utf16) >= 3 {
```

But that doesn't work. I now get the following error message instead.

```
'(String.UTF16View) -> _' is not identical to 'Int16'
```

What is the correct way to get the length of a string with Swift 1.2?

Comment: Right click on count, and "Jump to Definition".

Comment: From Swift 4+ you can use, `str.count`

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can use extension for it like:

```
extension String {
     var length: Int { return count(self)         }  // Swift 1.2
}
```

and you can use it:

```
if mystr.length >= 3 {

}
```

Or you can directly count this way:

```
if count(mystr) >= 3{

}
```

And this is also working for me :

```
if count(mystr.utf16) >= 3 {

}
```

For **Swift 2.0:**

```
extension String {
    var length: Int {
        return characters.count
    }
}
let str = "Hello, World"
str.length  //12
```

Another extension:

```
extension String {
    var length: Int {
        return (self as NSString).length
    }
}
let str = "Hello, World"
str.length //12
```

If you want direct use:

```
let str: String = "Hello, World"
print(str.characters.count) // 12

let str1: String = "Hello, World"
print(str1.endIndex) // 12

let str2 = "Hello, World"
NSString(string: str2).length  //12
```

Comment: Yeah I don't understand OP's error, its working for me too.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Even with count(mystr) I see the error  '(String) -> _' is not identical to 'Int16'.

Comment: Ah, I found it.  The NSManagedObject based class had a field called "count" defined as a Int16 that was overriding the global count function.  Thank you for the sanity check.

Answer (score 23):

You have to use characters property that contains the property count :

> yourString.characters.count

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 2.0 UPDATE**

```
extension String {
    var count: Int { return self.characters.count }
}
```

Use:

```
var str = "I love Swift 2.0!"
var n = str.count
```

[*Helpful Progamming Tips and Hacks*](https://gist.github.com/chess92)

Answer (score 6):

Here is all in one -- copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26516178/596360)

```
let str = "Hello"
let count = str.length    // returns 5 (Int)

extension String {
    var length: Int { return countElements(self) }  // Swift 1.1
}
extension String {
    var length: Int { return count(self)         }  // Swift 1.2
}
extension String {
    var length: Int { return characters.count    }  // Swift 2.0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`count(mystr)` is the correct way, you do not need to convert the encoding.

This: `if count(mystr.utf16) >= 3` is fine as long as you do `Int16(3)`

Edit: this is an old answer. OP updated his question to reflect Swift 2 and the above answer is correct.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but that gives me the error '(String) -> _' is not identical to 'Int16'.

Comment: Not the recommended way for doing that in Swift 2, instead see the @Dharmesh Kheni's answer above.

Comment: @King-Wizard I know, I saw it half a year ago.