# Swift 1.2 cannot invoke 'count' with an argument list of type '(String)'

Tags: swift, xcode6.3

Updated to Xcode 6.3.1 with new Swift 1.2, the old method `countElement` change to `count`, however when I switch to use `count`, it always throw out this error message:

> cannot invoke 'count' with an argument list of type '(String)'

This snippet is I copied from Apple doc, but still not working.

```
func printAndCount(stringToPrint: String) -> Int {
    println(stringToPrint)
    return count(stringToPrint)
}

func printWithoutCounting(stringToPrint: String) {
    printAndCount(stringToPrint)
}

printAndCount("hello, world")
```

Comment: That code compiles and runs without problems in my Xcode 6.3.1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [String length in Swift 1.2 and Swift 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29575140/string-length-in-swift-1-2-and-swift-2-0)

Answer (score 4):

Try calling the global `count` function with the `Swift` module prefix like this:

`Swift.count(stringToPoint)`

E.g. when extending the Array type there is a property named count as well and thus there is a naming conflict.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a bug, but adding to all my 'count' calls the Swift module prefix did solve this problem! Great tip Klaas, you saved my day!

Answer (score 3):

Did you declare the variable "count" in the same scope?
If so, you should change the variable name. And try to build again.

Comment: Seems like  a bug to me.

Comment: Doh. Not a bug since the scope overriding is behaving as expected, but it's an easy mistake to make, and the error message is not helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it was making me crazy.

To solve it, I used:

```
 myString.characters.count
```

Bingo.

Comment: I also had the same problem and prefixing `Swift` didn't work for me. But your answer actually worked. No idea how this bug came about

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried a clean and build? It works here.

Comment: Well, I create a new playground and the code works fine. I guess it's because the previous playground swift version messed up.

Comment: Sometimes you just need to reload it (by quitting Xcode or cutting and pasting code).

Answer (score -1):

Well, I create a new playground and copy the code works fine. I guess it's because the previous playground swift version messed up. Create a new project works fine.