# Swift error: 'count' is unavailable: there is no universally good answer, see the documentation comment for discussion

Tags: ios, swift

I am attempting to use `count` on a String.

```
var items = String()

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  return items.count // Error: 'count' is unavailable
}
```

This gives the error:

> Error: 'count' is unavailable: there is no universally good answer, see the documentation comment for discussion

Why is `count` unavailable? Why is there no "universally good answer"? How can I get the number of items in the String?

Comment: This is an older error message. In modern Swift, you *can* use `.count` to [Get the length of a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037711/get-the-length-of-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

Your class SecondViewController has an instance variable `items`. `items` is a `String`.

Strings do not have a property `count`, so the expression `items.count` is not valid.

From the fact that the name is a plural, and that you seem to be trying to use it to fetch content for cells, perhaps `items` should be an array of strings?

```
var items = ["string1", "string2", "string3"] //type [String]
```

Then in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` the code should index into the array:

```
cell!.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]
```