# Converting CountElements to Swift 3 not working when trying to shorten text

Tags: swift, xcode, swift2, swift3

Hey I am having a problem trying to convert this old code into swift 3:

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {

           let components = self.txtBody.text.componentsSeparatedByString("    \n") 
           self.navigationItem.title = ""

           for item in components {

             if countElements(item.trimmingCharacters(in: NSCharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines())) > 0 {


               self.navigationItem.title = item  

              break
     }
   }
 }
```

The problem is the countElements is not correct as it is not recognised in Swift. I am unsure how to convert it to swift 3

Any help or guidance would be great thanks

Harraj

Comment: Convert countElements to count

Comment: so simply change countElements to count??

Comment: @HarrajSinghMann Yes like this `item.trimmingCharacters(in: NSCharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines()).count`

Comment: @HarrajSinghMann, no, `countElements` is function, `count` is property. And I thought it changed in Swift 2. Your code looks very 1.0ish

Comment: @user28434 the code is from Swift 1.0 I am following a tutorial trying to convert it to swift 3 you see... I've managed to do all of it but I am stuck on this bit..

Comment: @HarrajSinghMann user28434 is right: count has been for some time a global function, then was definetely converted to a property

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037711/get-the-length-of-a-string

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! Managed to fix it and run with no errors.. only problem is that It is not doing what it is intended to do in the tutorial :( It won't edit my title for the notes..

Comment: @HarrajSinghMann Post another question