# UITextView Class, intrinsicContentSize issue from Objective-C to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitextview, intrinsic-content-size

I have always worked in **Objective-C**, I have been using **Swift** for a short time .. I had a `UITextView` class in **Objective-C** where I was working on the `intrinsicContentSize` method.

---

**Objective-C**

```
-(CGSize)intrinsicContentSize {
    if ([self.text length]) return self.contentSize;
    else return CGSizeZero;
}
```

Now I'm trying to convert my Objective-C code to Swift but I'm having problems with this function ...

```
 override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
         if text.lenght() {
              return contentSize
          } else {
              return CGSize.zero
          }
    }
```

`text.lenght` appears to give me a

> Value of type error '(UITextRange) -> String? has no member 'length'

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037711/get-the-length-of-a-string the way to retrieve the length of the string is different in Swift

Comment: @ArikSegal I tried to replace text.length context.count or text.character.count but it keeps giving me the same error .. for this reason I can't understand where I'm wrong

Comment: Typo in code: `lenght` → `length`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the length of a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037711/get-the-length-of-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return text.isEmpty ? .zero : contentSize
}
```

intrinsic content size depends on text length (number of characters in a string) and we return the size that is needed

Comment: `text.isEmpty` would be a better solution.

Comment: @Sulthan exactly, I've updated code

Answer (score 0):

You can use like it below in `swift`

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
     if self.text.count > 0 {
        return contentSize
     } else {
        return CGSize.zero
     }
 }
```

Hope It will help you.