# How can I rewrite this in swift 4 or 5

Tags: swift

I get an error saying **'characters' is unavailable: Please use String directly**.

```
extension LoginViewController : UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField,
                   shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
                   replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        if let username = self.usernameField.text,
            let password = self.passwordField.text {

            if ((username.characters.count > 0) && //This is where I get the error
                (password.characters.count > 0)) { //This is where I get the error
                self.loginButton.isEnabled = true
            }
        }

        return true
    }

}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: username and password are Strings . The error message is giving you a hint here.

Comment: `username.count` and `password.count`?  The `count` property is a direct part of String class, at least in Swift 5.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037711/get-the-length-of-a-string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the length of a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037711/get-the-length-of-a-string)

Comment: @JohnMontgomery: great minds think alike.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove `.characters`

```
extension LoginViewController : UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField,
                   shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
                   replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        if let username = self.usernameField.text,
            let password = self.passwordField.text {

            if username.count > 0 &&
                password.count > 0 {
                self.loginButton.isEnabled = true
            }
        }

        return true
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to state characters to count since it will already be counted when you type username.count or password.count

if ((username.count > 0) &&
    (password.count > 0)) {

Answer (score 2):

In Swift never check for empty string or empty collection type with `.count > 0`, there is the dedicated method `isEmpty`.

And in Swift parentheses around `if` expressions are not needed and the `&&` operator can be replaced with a comma

```
if !self.usernameField.text!.isEmpty, !self.passwordField.text!.isEmpty {
    self.loginButton.isEnabled = true
}
```

The `text` property of `UITextField` is never `nil` so force unwrapping is fine.