# NSPredicate with ANY and "=nil" doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

This condition works

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
       @"ANY region.beacons.major = %d",rangedBeacon.major.intValue];
```

But this not

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
       @"ANY region.beacons.minor = nil"];
```

beacons is a list inside region object. Major and minor have type NSNumber

Comment: What is your minor value ? is it zero?

Comment: It can be nil. Nil - this is not zero.

Comment: can u print beacons

Comment: I don't understand why you keep reposting your question instead of modifying it, narrowing down your issue. Do you have a sample for regions & beacons? Also, are your filtering a array ? Doing a CoreData Request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution

Because of ANY and "=nil" can't be in the same condition (explanation is here [Core Data, NSPredicate, ANY key.path == nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193872/core-data-nspredicate-any-key-path-nil))? solution of this problem looks like:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
      @"SUBQUERY(region.beacons, $x, $x.minor == nil)"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY region.beacons.minor = $minor"];
predicate = [predicate predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:
[NSDictionary  dictionaryWithObject:[NSNull null] forKey: @"minor"]];
```

Comment: No, unfortunately.

Comment: You may check this link as you said major and minor are NSNumber, for checking empty values:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716599/check-if-nsnumber-is-empty