# String isNullOrEmpty as a category

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, null, objective-c-category

I'm trying to create a method which checks for a null/nil/empty string, and I'm trying to get it working as a category but having no luck.

I'm using this code, based on answers in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899209/how-do-i-test-if-a-string-is-empty-in-objective-c):

```
@implementation NSString (NSStringExtension)
- (BOOL)isNullOrEmpty {
    return self == nil || 
    self == (id)[NSNull null] ||
    [@"" isEqualToString:self] || 
    [[self stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""] length] == 0||
    [self isEqualToString:@"(null)"]
     || ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(length)] && [(NSData *) self length] == 0)
     || ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(count)] && [(NSArray *) self count] == 0)
     || [[self stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] length] == 0;
}
@end
```

Yet when I try to use this this is what I get:

```
NSLog([@"" isNullOrEmpty] ? @"1":@"0"); // prints 1
NSString *s1 = nil;
NSLog([s1 isNullOrEmpty] ? @"1":@"0"); // prints 0
NSLog([args.itemName isNullOrEmpty] ? @"1":@"0"); // prints 0
NSLog([(NSString*)nil isNullOrEmpty] ? @"1":@"0"); // prints 0
```

This is baffling me, and I can only assume that some combination of iOS5/ARC is causing the nil object to be coerced to a blank string/pointer. The debugger shows the string as 0x0, yet when I use my `isNullOrEmpty` method, I get false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
return self == nil
```

This can never happen. If you try to send `isNullOrEmpty` (or any other message) to `nil`, nothing happens (`objc_msgSend()`, the function responsible for message dispatch, checks for a `nil` reciever as one of the first things it does and aborts).

```
self == (id)[NSNull null]
```

This will also never happen. If you send `isNullOrEmpty` to an object that's an instance of `NSNull`, your method here, which is a method on `NSString`, will not be called. Instead, `NSNull`'s version (which probably doesn't exist) will be.

Likewise, `([self respondsToSelector:@selector(count)] && [(NSArray *) self count])` is never going to happen. If the object *is* an `NSArray`, then `isNullOrEmpty` will never run, because, again, it's a method of `NSString`.

Correspondingly, `[(NSData *) self length]` doesn't do what you think it does. `NSString` instances *do* respond to `length`, but casting the object to `NSData` doesn't use the `NSData` version of the method -- it still ends up as the `NSString` version of `length`, because the object *actually is* an `NSString` (casting only happens at compile-time; it can't change anything at run-time).

```
[self isEqualToString:@"(null)"]
```

Here you appear to be checking for `nil` again, but you are being misled by the *representation* that `NSLog` chooses when it prints `nil`:

```
NSLog(@"%@", nil);
```

This displays `(null)` in the console, but that doesn't mean that the object itself is a string with those characters. `NSLog` just chooses that string to display for `nil`.*

Several of the things you are doing would require this to be in a category on `NSObject`, so that the method *would* in fact be called even if the object was not an `NSString`.

To check for a string consisting only of whitespace, all you need is the comparison to the empty string `@""` after trimming whitespace:

```
NSString * trimmedSelf = [self stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
// Then either:
[trimmedSelf isEqualToString:@""];
// Or:
([trimmedSelf length] == 0);
```

---

*And even better, doing `NSLog(@"%@", [NSNull null]);` displays `<null>` (angle brackets instead of parentheses), wonderfully confusing the first few times you encounter `NSNull`.

Comment: Interesting. Seems to make it work the way I want, I need to check whether `someString == nil || [someString isNullOrEmpty]`

Comment: @Echilon: If you reverse the semantics of `isNullOrEmpty`, and make it `isNotEmpty`, you can condense that to simply `[someString isNotEmpty]`, since if `someString` is `nil`, it will also return 0/false/`NO`.

Comment: this is bad...trim and then check if it's the empty set? you should iterate through each character and if you encounter a character return false.

Comment: @pqsk: Feel free to post your own answer. I don't like the sound of your solution, though; you can't iterate an `NSString` directly, and you'll need to compare each and every character against the set of whitespace characters. Try it. You'll have to get each character from your string, then put that back into a string -- a waste of time.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I know this is 2 years later, but you wrote what I had said. Obviously you can't iterate through an NSString, hence why I said "each character". Why would you want to put it back into a string? That is a total waste of time like you said, but I never said such thing. Like I said, the moment there is a character that is not an empty space, you return false at that point. Thing is with  your solution it's fine on some strings, but it wouldn't scale up for any big strings.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach can be to define a simple macro.

```
#define NSStringIsNullOrEmpty(str) ((str==nil) || [(str) isEqualToString:@""])
```

It's simple and effective. If you do not like macros you can always convert it to a function call without affecting the rest of your code.

-- Update:

@Bryan has raised a good point. An inline function is a great way to go. Here is an updated macro that will evaluate str only once.

```
#define NSStringIsNullOrEmpty(str) ({ NSString *_str=(str); ((tmp==nil) || [tmp isEqualToString:@""]);})
```

Comment: be careful `str` get evaluated twice. use inline function is much better than macro

Comment: the variable tmp isn't defined in that function, just swap out tmp for _str.

#define NSStringIsNullOrEmpty(str) ({ NSString *_str=(str); ((_str==nil) || [_str isEqualToString:@""]);})

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C, sending a message to nil will always return 0 (or `NO`, a zeroed-out struct, NULL, etc., depending on the declared return type). The `isNullOrEmpty` method that you wrote won't actually be invoked when you send `isNullOrEmpty` to `nil`. See the accepted answer to [Sending a message to nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156395/sending-a-message-to-nil) for more information.

Perhaps you could change your method to be `isNotNullOrEmpty`. Then a return value of 0 when sending `isNotNullOrEmpty` to `nil` will make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling your method, but **sending a message to nil**.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. You are sending a message to `nil` after all. So it is returning either nil (or some other 0 value). Which short circuits to false so that '0' is printed in the cases shown below:

```
NSLog([s1 isNullOrEmpty] ? @"1":@"0"); // prints 0
NSLog([(NSString*)nil isNullOrEmpty] ? @"1":@"0"); // prints 0
```

You can even confirm your message is not being called for those cases by setting a breakpoint in your new category method.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, calling `[nil isNullOrEmpty];` will not actually run your method.  The `nil` object is just that : empty itself.

As a solution, I'd like to say that it's not because you're in an Object-Oriented language that you must never use functions.

```
BOOL IsStringNilOrEmpty(NSString*)str
{
    return str == nil ||
        str == null ||
        [@"" isEqualToString:str] ||
        [[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""] length] == 0||
        [str isEqualToString:@"(null)"]
        || ([str respondsToSelector:@selector(length)] && [(NSData *) str length] == 0)
        || ([str respondsToSelector:@selector(count)] && [(NSArray *) str count] == 0)
        || [[str stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] length] == 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

actually I just fixed this problem by turning it around like so

```
-(BOOL) isNotNullOrWhiteSpace
{
        return [self length] != 0 && [[self stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] length] != 0;
}
```

so instead of isNullOrWhiteSpace it's isNotNullOrWhiteSpace.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my method of checking null/empty

-(NSString*)NULLInputinitWithString:(NSString*)InputString 
{

```
if( (InputString == nil) ||(InputString ==(NSString*)[NSNull null])||([InputString isEqual:nil])||([InputString length] == 0)||([InputString isEqualToString:@""])||([InputString isEqualToString:@"(NULL)"])||([InputString isEqualToString:@"<NULL>"])||([InputString isEqualToString:@"<null>"]||([InputString isEqualToString:@"(null)"])||([InputString isEqualToString:@"NULL"]) ||([InputString isEqualToString:@"null"])))

    return @"";
else
    return InputString ;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Have you thought about creating a class method on a category that extends NSString?

NSString+NSStringExtensions.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSString(NSStringExtensions)
+(BOOL)isNilOrEmpty:(NSString*)string;
@end
```

NSString+NSStringExtensions.m

```
#import "NSString+NSStringExtensions.h"

@implementation NSString(NSStringExtensions)

+(BOOL)isNilOrEmpty:(NSString*)string
{
    if (nil == string)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    if (string.length == 0)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

@end
```

Then you use it like this:

```
#import "NSString+NSStringExtensions.h"
...
NSLog([NSString isNilOrEmpty:@""] ? @"1":@"0");
```

Comment: make it one line:`return string.length == 0;`. and don't call NSLog like that

Comment: @BryanChen I don't write a whole lot of Ocjective-C. Can you elaborate on why NSLog shouldn't be called like that?

Comment: it should be `NSLog(@"%@", [NSString isNilOrEmpty:@""] ? @"1":@"0")` or `NSLog(@"%d", [NSString isNilOrEmpty:@""] ? 1 : 0)`