# What the meaning of question mark '?' in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

In Swift programming I found some question marks with objects.

```
var window: UIWindow?
```

Can anybody explain the use of it?

Comment: @Vladimir,angelo  can't i learn from stackOverflow?

Comment: Downvotes doesn't necessarily mean a question shouldn't be here. They are a statement on their quality and the research effort put into them. You can learn through Stack Overflow instead of going through the language reference. It's your choice. But the downvotes might be the price.

Comment: But this question will helpful for other user also, because no one have such time to read book..

Comment: @MattGibson - Now a day everyone just type query on Goole, for this basic thing who will search the complete book? like if i want to know that how to addObject in array, then i will just google it, no one will search pages of complete book to get a basic question, i also seared this question before on google, but didn't found any reliable solution.

Comment: @Rajneesh071 it is because it's so basic and available people didn't need the help of others to answer that question

Comment: @Angelo - Ok , but my message for the down-voter that go to this question if you really want to down-vote basic question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899209/how-do-i-test-if-a-string-is-empty-in-objective-c

Comment: Seriously? Testing if a string is empty in Objective C sometimes results to false positive even with right syntax or logic. Basic yes, definitive no. Your question however is answered definitively in the iBook guide.

Comment: Basically means the kind of variable which either has a value OR is nil, representing it does not have a value. Refer to The Swift Programming Language, available on iBooks

Answer (score 68, accepted):

> You can use `if` and `let` together to work with values that might be
>   missing. These values are represented as `optionals`. An `optional`
>   value either contains a value or contains `nil` to indicate that the
>   value is missing. Write a question mark (?) after the type of a value
>   to mark the value as `optional`.
>
> If the optional value is `nil`, the conditional is `false` and the code in
>   braces is skipped. Otherwise, the optional value is unwrapped and
>   assigned to the constant after `let`, which makes the unwrapped value
>   available inside the block of code.

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/pk/jEUH0.l

For Example:

```
var optionalString: String? = "Hello"
optionalString == nil

var optionalName: String? = "John Appleseed"
var greeting = "Hello!"
if let name = optionalName {
    greeting = "Hello, \(name)"
}
```

In this code, the output would be `Hello! John Appleseed`. And if we set the value of `optionalName` as `nil`. The `if` conditional result would be `false` and code inside that `if` would get skipped.

Comment: I think the result of  `greeting` is "Hello, John Appleseed" while if `optionalName` is `nil` the result will be "Hello!", the comma and exclamation mark actually help me to understand it better

Answer (score 23):

Question marks after a type refer to `Optionals`, a way in Swift which lets you indicate the possibility that a value might be absent for any type at all, without the need for special constants.

It's used in the same situations you'd explicitly `return nil` in Objective-C, when there is no object to be returned, or for values that are not objects, constants such as `NSNotFound`. Optionals provide a consistent way of achieving this across all data types.

From the Apple provided iBook

> You use optionals in situations where a value may be absent. An
>   optional says:
>
> - There is a value, and it equals x
>
> or
>
> - There isn’t a value at all
>
> Here’s an example. Swift’s String type has a method called toInt,
>   which tries to convert a String value into an Int value. However, not
>   every string can be converted into an integer. The string "123" can be
>   converted into the numeric value 123, but the string "hello, world"
>   does not have an obvious numeric value to convert to.

```
let possibleNumber = "123"
let convertedNumber = possibleNumber.toInt()
// convertedNumber is inferred to be of type "Int?", or "optional Int"
```

> Because the toInt method might fail, it returns an optional Int,
>   rather than an Int. An optional Int is written as Int?, not Int. The
>   question mark indicates that the value it contains is optional,
>   meaning that it might contain some Int value, or it might contain no
>   value at all. (It can’t contain anything else, such as a Bool value or
>   a String value. It’s either an Int, or it’s nothing at all.)

There is a whole section on the language reference iBook on Optionals, and they are mentioned several times throughout the book. You should have a thorough look at it, since it's a fundamental concept of Swift programming, and one that is not prevalent in many other languages.

Comment: let posString = "123"
let convertString = posString.Int()
convertString

Value of type 'String' has no number 'Int'

Answer (score 2):

the optional Value of the type .

For Ex : 
the optional version of the type casting operator : `as?` ,mean `as` use for the type casting with might be optional to cast .