# as! vs as operator in Xcode 6.3 in Swift

Tags: swift, casting

Swift changed a lot with Xcode 6.3. I had to replace dozens of places in each of my app `as` -> `as!`. Why, what are the rules now?

Comment: Documented in the Xcode 6.3 release notes and in the Swift blog: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=23.

Comment: ... also covered in the online documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID338, or in previous SO questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29637974/swift-typecasting-in-1-2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prior to Swift 1.2, the `as` operator could be used to carry out two different kinds of conversion, depending on the type of expression being converted and the type it was being converted to:

- **Guaranteed conversion** of a value of one type to another, whose success can be verified by the Swift compiler. For example, upcasting (i.e., converting from a class to one of its superclasses) or specifying the type of a literal expression, (e.g., 1 as Float).
- **Forced conversion** of one value to another, whose safety cannot be guaranteed by the Swift compiler and which may cause a runtime trap. For example downcasting, converting from a class to one of its subclasses.

Swift 1.2 separates the notions of guaranteed conversion and forced conversion into two distinct operators. Guaranteed conversion is still performed with the `as` operator, but forced conversion now uses the `as!` operator. The `!` is meant to indicate that the conversion may fail. This way, you know at a glance which conversions may cause the program to crash.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=23

Answer (score 1):

The practical difference is this:

```
var optionalString = dict.objectForKey("SomeKey") as? String
```

`optionalString` will be a variable of type `String?`. If the underlying type is something other than a `String` this will harmlessly just assign `nil` to the optional.

```
var optionalString = dict.objectForKey("SomeKey") as! String?
```

This says, I know this thing is a `String?`. This too will result in `optionalString` being of type `String?`, but it will crash if the underlying type is something else.

The first style is then used with `if let` to safely unwrap the optional:

```
if let string = dict.objectForKey("SomeKey") as? String {
    // If I get here, I know that "SomeKey" is a valid key in the dictionary, I correctly
    // identified the type as String, and the value is now unwrapped and ready to use.  In
    // this case "string" has the type "String".
    println(string)
}
```

Comment: Please don't copy other's answers.  If you think it answers the question, post a link in a comment.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/25710162/1630618

Answer (score 0):

According to the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH4-DontLinkElementID_34):

> The notions of guaranteed conversion and “forced failable” conversion
>   are now separated into two operators. Forced failable conversion now
>   uses the as! operator. The ! makes it clear to readers of code that
>   the cast may fail and produce a runtime error. The “as” operator
>   remains for upcasts (e.g. “someDerivedValue as Base”) and type
>   annotations (“0 as Int8”) which are guaranteed to never fail.