# What is the difference between Swift "as" and "as!" type casting operations?

Tags: swift, types, type-conversion

Why are there `as` vs. `as!` vs. `as?` type casting in Swift ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Downcasting optionals in Swift: as? Type, or as! Type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25708649/downcasting-optionals-in-swift-as-type-or-as-type) or http://stackoverflow.com/q/29637974/2792531 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/29674986/2792531

Comment: I can't agree, I've reviewed all the above questions before posting, to my preference none speaks of the 3 various operations in a concise clear and easy to understand way. I've made this question to be as clear as possible coupled with demo code for future seekers, and as such I wouldn't call it a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`as` is compile time cast

`as?` and `as!` are runtime casts

- `as?` will cast, if cast not possible will return Optional(nil)
- `as!` will cast, if cast not possible will crash with runtime error

Example:

```
class Music { }
class Pop: Music { }
class Rock: Music { }

Pop() as Music // OK, some might disagree but Music *is* a super class of Pop
Pop() as Rock  // Compile error: 'Pop' is not convertable to 'Rock'

let pop: AnyObject = Pop()

pop as Music // Compile error: 'AnyObject' is not convertible to 'Music'

pop as? Pop // Pop
pop as! Pop // Pop
pop as? Music // Pop
pop as! Music // Pop

pop as? Rock // nil
pop as! Rock // Runtime error signal SIGABRT
```

Comment: I wouldn't call `as?` forced.  `as?` is optional.  `as` and `as!` are forced, `as` is safe, `as!` is not safe.

Comment: @nhgrif I think you're right about the forced categorisation, i'll rewrite my answer.