# Swift casting statement with CF -> NS classes

Tags: ios, swift

While trying to integrate the Address Book framework and converting CF types to NS Classes to Swift classes, I noticed something strange:

`ABRecordCopyCompositeName(record)?.takeRetainedValue() as? NSString`

returns `nil`

`ABRecordCopyCompositeName(record)?.takeRetainedValue() as NSString?`

returns `Optional("John Smith")`

My question is that isn't `as? NSString` synonymous to `as NSString? as? NSString`? (If so, why not?)

Therefore,
`ABRecordCopyCompositeName(record)?.takeRetainedValue() as? NSString`
should be equivalent to
`ABRecordCopyCompositeName(record)?.takeRetainedValue() as NSString? as? NSString`
which should return "John Smith".

(This was working on iOS 8.3, but iOS 8.4 broke my AddressBook feature.)

Comment: "99%" duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25708649/downcasting-optionals-in-swift-as-type-or-as-type.

Comment: not really, the topic does not mention the bridge (`as`) operator

Comment: Not a duplicate. I understand the usage of `as` vs `as?` vs `as!`. I'm asking if `as? NSString` === `as NSString? as? NSString` and why iOS 8.4 broke `as? NSString` returns nil that while dealing with CFString classes.

Answer (score 1):

`as (NS)String?` is no supported syntax, even it might work in some way.
Either you can cast forced (`as!`) or optional (`as?`) or you can bridge (`as`) and there's no exclamation/question mark after the type.

`ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople()` returns `Unmanaged<CFArray>!` and `ABRecordCopyCompositeName()` returns `Unmanaged<CFString>!`, both types are unwrapped optionals, so after calling `takeRetainedValue()` you can bridge to `NSString`

```
ABRecordCopyCompositeName(record).takeRetainedValue() as NSString
```

or further to `String`

```
ABRecordCopyCompositeName(record).takeRetainedValue() as NSString as String
```

Comment: `as NSString?` *is* supported, e.g. if applied to a `CFString?`.

Comment: Do you have a source? I couldn't find it in the Language Guide. if `as` is followed by a type, the marks are always right after `as`

Comment: `NSString?` *is* a type, it is `Optional<NSString>`.

Comment: Might be but I've never seen `as <Type>?` (`as` without and `<Type>` with a mark) in Swift code provided by Apple

Comment: Can Unmanaged<CFString>! ever return nil? (It seems unclear since it's an unmanaged class, and hence why I'm utilizing either an optional class or an optional cast)

Comment: Additionally, `as NSString?` is supported syntax because you are intentionally casting it to be an optional class. The cast operation itself is orthogonal to the class it is being cast to.