# Terminology of Optionals in Swift or other languages

Tags: swift, language-agnostic, option-type

In Swift the elements we manipulates all have types.

When we use theses types, we can add a '*!*', '*?*' or *nothing* to express their nullability.

1. What shall I call the '*?*' or '*!*' used to express this trait ?

A type decorator ? A decorator ? Operator ? Something else ?

2. What shall I call the type created when using this character ?

Is it a new type ? Is it a decorated type ? A type variation ?

The swift compiler, seems to consider them as new types, However my question is not implementation or language dependent and therefor I tagged it as language agnostic.

Edit: **I'm looking for a language agnostic name.** I understand with pranjalsatija's comment optionals are defined as `compound type`.
However, this is a language implementation detail.
I could rephrase my questions as:

**What do you call a character with a special meaning when used it a type definition, and how to call the derived type**.

This term should probably apply to capital casing constants in ruby as the concept is similar.

Answer (score 7):

`?` on the end of the type isn’t a decorator or operator. It’s hardcoded syntactic sugar in Swift that allows you to shorten `Optional<Thing>` to `Thing?`.

The `?` doesn’t really have a name (at least I’ve never heard anyone on the Swift team use one), in the language reference it’s just described as “the postfix `?`”. The language grammar doesn’t put it in a syntactic category.

Similarly, `[Thing]` is shorthand for `Array<Thing>`, but there isn’t a name for the square brackets in this context.

Describing `Option<Int>` as “derived from” `Int` would be to misuse the term “derived”.  You can if you want describe it as “`Optional` specialized for `Int`”.

In fact you may be looking for the language-agnostic term for how Swift allows you to build types (like `Optional<T>` or `Array<T>`) that apply to any kind of type `T` without having to care what `T` actually is.  In which case the term would probably be [generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming).

`!` is a little different.  When applied to a type name as in `Thing!`, it’s shorthand for `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Thing>`, in the same manner as `?`.

`!` when applied to a variable of type `Thing?` is equivalent to a postfix operator that tests the optional and if it is `nil`, terminates your program, something like this:

```
postfix operator !<T>(value: T?) -> T {
    if let unwrapped = value {
        return unwrapped
    }
    else {
       fatalError("unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value")
    }
}
```

so in this context, `!` can be described as an operator.  But not in the first context.

For the terminology a given language uses to describe optionals, see the [Option type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type) wikipedia page.

Answer (score 0):

Optionals in Swift technically are completely different types, not variations of the same type. However, to a developer, they seem to be variations, so we'll treat them as such. The ? and the ! don't really have a set, specified name just yet, at least not that I know of. In a sense, you shouldn't be calling them type decorators, because optionals are really new types on their own. So to answer your question, the ? and the ! are parts of a type's name, more than anything else. And the new type created when using a ? or an ! is just that. A brand new type.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html look at this link for more detail about how Optionals work. Basically, Apple says that Optionals are defined separately, and writing String? is the same as writing Optional<String>. If you read the document, you'll see what I mean. The ? and the ! are actually syntax sugar, to make writing code easier, so they're not really called type decorators, or operators.

Comment: The new type created seems to be more an implementation than a concept, I don't think it should affect the terminology as this is a Swift specific thing. Pointers, classes, enumerations are all concepts, even if the actual implementation and behavior defers from one language to an other.

Answer (score 0):

The type created using '?' is an Optional and '!' is an Implicitly Unwrapped Optional

I think the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122601/swift-variable-decorations-with-question-mark-and-exclamation-mark) may help you out, they refer to both as decorations

[Here's a larger explanation about exclamation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018327/what-does-an-exclamation-mark-mean-in-the-swift-language)

[And here's one for question marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24057171/what-the-meaning-of-question-mark-in-swift)