# Why latest Swift version always says variable is not initialized before use

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Take an example

```
Class A {

var a : Int

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        a=0
}
```

when it says variable is not initialized, even when i already declared in class first.

Comment: Because `viewDidLoad` is not equivalent of `init`.

Comment: just add `var a: Int?`

Comment: it works thanks. but my question is,i already declared a as integer why i am not able to assign value to it.

Comment: Because variables must be initialized in an `init` method or in the declaration line.

Comment: Just read for more information :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24057171/what-the-meaning-of-question-mark-in-swift

Comment: @mitulmarsonia That's not a question about optionals.

Comment: @vadian  I just explain about "?".

Comment: you all guys are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` is not the equivalent of `init`

I suggest you either use optionals:

```
var a:Int?
```

or you can initialize your variable directly in its declaration

```
var a:Int = 0
```

Last but not least, if you want to initialize any other way, do it in the init

```
override init() {
    super.init()

    a = 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when you declare property in the class with Int it indicates it has no initializers. either give value at initialize time `var a : Int = 0`
or give value using init block which is use initialize the property of class. or you can also give declare as optional with ? `var x : Int?`

```
override init() {
super.init()
a = 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift performs Two phase initialization :

> **Two-Phase Initialization** 
>
>   Class initialization in Swift is a two-phase
>   process. In the first phase, each stored property is assigned an
>   initial value by the class that introduced it. Once the initial state
>   for every stored property has been determined, the second phase
>   begins, and each class is given the opportunity to customize its
>   stored properties further before the new instance is considered ready
>   for use.”

Basically, this means that a property is not ready for use till it is provided an initial value.

In Objective-C, this was handled internally as the properties were set *nil* or *0* (depending on the data type) until initialized.

This behavior is provided by **Optionals** in Swift.

> “You use optionals in situations where a value may be absent. An
>   optional says:
>
> There is a value, and it equals x or
>
> There isn’t a value at all”

As mentioned by other answers, you can declare an optional using a **"?"**

eg: `var a : Int?`

For details refer : [The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.2).](https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l)