# how to check condition with "<null>" in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

1. I want to check that the maxprice is equal to "" this or not if it's "" then maxprice will become maxprice = 0

**my Json**

```
price = ({
    maxprice = "<null>";
    minprice = "<null>";
});
```

**code**

```
var Arr = NSArray()

Arr = result.value(forKey: "price") as! NSArray
let max = Arr.value(forKey: "maxprice")

if max == nil {
    self.MaxValue = 0
    self.MinValue = 0
}

else {
    let maxval =  (Arr.object(at: 0) as AnyObject).value(forKey: "maxprice") as! NSNumber
    let min =  (Arr.object(at: 0) as AnyObject).value(forKey: "minprice") as! NSNumber

    self.MaxValue = maxval
    self.MinValue = min
}
```

> Error: Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x102148918) to
>   'NSNumber' (0x10311c4a8).

Comment: if you want string as "" (empty) then you can use string.isEmpty (Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133157/check-empty-string-in-swift)

Comment: i want to check that "<null>"

Comment: If you mean literally the string `<null>` you can just check `if max == "<null>"`. If you mean the Swift value nil, you should use a null coalescing operator: `MaxValue = blahblah ?? 0`

Comment: Actually throwing any non-numeric string into `as? Int` will result in `nil`, so that's probably the way to go.

Comment: This is Swift. Do not use `NSArray`, this avoids a horrible syntax like `... as AnyObject).value(forKey: "maxprice")` and do not use `valueForKey` unless you can explain why you need KVC. And why `NSNumber`? There are native types (`Int`, `Double`) in Swift

Answer (score 12):

You can also use `is` to check for the presence of a null:

```
if Arr.value(forKey: "maxprice") is NSNull {
    // do something with null JSON value here
}
```

Comment: Is this ObjectiveC style? I think in Swift you want `if Blah == nil { ... }`, or better yet, unbox the optional at the same time using `if let unboxed = Blah { // use unboxed }`

Comment: this is checking the value is null or not in swift.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3.0**

You can get this in short line of code using `??` as like below also we can say rescue operation.

```
let max = Arr.value(forKey: "maxprice") as? NSNumber ?? 0
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the Swift way.

Use **optional bindings** and do not use *objectivecish* `NSArray`, `valueForKey` and `NSNumber`

You need to check

- if the value for key `price` is a Swift array of dictionaries (`[[String:Double]]`). The distinct type avoids the extra check for `NSNull`
- if the array is not empty.

---

Assuming `minprice` and `maxprice` are supposed to be `Double` values, if not replace `Double` with `Int`

```
if let priceArray = jsonDict["price"] as? [[String:Double]],
    let price = priceArray.first {
    minValue = price["minprice"] ?? 0.0
    maxValue = price["maxprice"] ?? 0.0
} else {
    minValue = 0.0
    maxValue = 0.0
}
```