# Check if passed argument value is nil or empty

Tags: c#, swift

I am trying to re-write the C# code which i have wrote previously to Swift.

```
public static string Right( string value, int length)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return string.Empty;
    return value.Length <= length ? value : value.Substring(value.Length - length);
}
```

I am not able to write if statement effectively in swift.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check empty string in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133157/check-empty-string-in-swift)

Comment: Duplicate post, please check in repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `prefix` and ?: as a one-liner

```
func right(value: String, length: Int) -> String {
    return value.count > length ? String(value.prefix(value.count - length)) : value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `Swift` you can write,

```
func right(value: String, length: Int) -> String {
    if value.count <= length {
        return value
    } else {
        let index = value.index(value.startIndex, offsetBy: value.count-length)
        return String(value[..<index])
    }
}
```

There is no need to check for `empty string`. It will be covered in the `else condition` itself.

**Example:**

```
right(value: "abcdefgh", length: 3) //abcde
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done as simple as that:

```
func right(value: String, length: Int) -> String {
    guard value.count > length, length > 0 else { return value }
    return String(
        value.dropLast(length) // we just drop `length` number of elements from the end
    )
}
```